# Java string too long?

Tags: java, string

I have the following code in Java (which worked just fine in C++ for some reason) which produces an error:

```
int a;
System.out.println("String length: " + input.length());
for(a = 0; ((a + 1) * 97) < input.length(); a++) {
    System.out.print("Substring at " + a + ": ");
    System.out.println(input.substring(a * 97, 97));
    //other code here...
}
```

Output:

```
String length: 340
Substring at 0: HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHe
Substring at 1: 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -97
//long list of "at ..." stuff
Substring at 2:
```

Using a string of length 200, however, the following output is produced:

```
String length: 200
Substring at 0: HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHe
Substring at 1:
```

That is it; no exceptions raised, just... nothing. What is happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second parameter to [String.substring](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) is the *last index* not the length of the substring. So you want the following (I assume):

```
int a;
System.out.println("String length: " + input.length());
for(a = 0; ((a + 1) * 97) < input.length(); a++) {
    System.out.print("Substring at " + a + ": ");
    System.out.println(input.substring(a * 97, (a + 1) * 97));
    //other code here...
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you! Things are a bit different from C++ :)